# Difficulties with posting data to Google Firebase HTTP Functions

Tags: node.js, express, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to POST some variables as part of `req.body` to a Firebase Cloud Function. I am using the modern `fetch()` syntax as following:

```
const { licenseCode } = this.state;
fetch('https://myAPI.com/inputLicense', {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({ licenseCode })
})
```

And here is how my Cloud function looks:

```
exports.inputLicense = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
  // const { licenseCode } = request.body
  console.log(request.get('content-type'))
  console.log('query', request.query)
  console.log('body', request.body)
})
```

Unfortunately, all of the above logging produces empty objects or undefined in the case of the first line. In a usual Express setup, I know I need to use:

```
app.use(bodyParser.json()); // for parsing application/json
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true })); // for parsing application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```

But don't know how to do it with cloud functions. Google claims in their Docs they parse my requests automatically, based on the header but I just can't get it to work.

Any help is more then welcome, thanks in advance.

Comment: Your lambda code is correct. Have you ensured that there really is something in the object you're sending?

Comment: My other question would be: is there something in `request.rawBody`

Comment: rawBody is undefined in my case @MichaelMcQuade

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like you solved the problem, but for anyone else having a problem. In my case the problem was the firebase cloud function triggering on the [cors preflight request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Preflight_request) which contains no body.

I solved it by removing the application/json content-type in the fetch call and decoding the json body manually in the cloud function

```
// on the client
fetch(functionURL + '/' + name, {
    body: JSON.stringify({abc: 123}),
    method: 'POST',
    mode: 'cors',
})

// on the server
functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {
    const {abc} = JSON.parse(req.body)
    res.set('content-type', 'application/json')
    res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
    res.status(200)
    res.send({result: abc})
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I've done some tests and apparently the problem comes from the object destructuring.

The following should work:

```
const obj = { licenseCode: this.state };
fetch('https://myAPI.com/inputLicense', {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
  },
  body: JSON.stringify(obj)
})
```